# Values of a Dataframe Column into an Array in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Say, I have dataframe

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(List(
  ("A1",45, "5", 1, 90),
  ("A2",60, "1", 1, 120),
  ("A3", 45, "9", 1, 450),
  ("A4", 26, "7", 1, 333)
)).toDF("CID","age", "children", "marketplace_id","value")
```

Now I want all the values of column "**children**" into an separate array in the same order.

the below code works for smaller dataset with only one partition

```
val list1 = df.select("children").map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String]).collect()
```

output:

```
list1: Array[String] = Array(5, 1, 9, 7)
```

But the above code fails when we have partitions

```
val partitioned = df.repartition($"CID")
val list = partitioned.select("children").map(r => r(0).asInstanceOf[String]).collect()
```

output:

```
list: Array[String] = Array(9, 1, 7, 5)
```

is there way, that I can get all the values of a column into an array without changing an order?

Comment: This is non-deterministic because it depends on data partitioning and task scheduling.

Comment: @dumitru so there is no way we can achieve this?

Comment: you can try to add `monotonically_increasing_id()` column and after repartitioning sort by that column